# Derivative of Log Determinant of a Matrix w.r.t a scalar parameter

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following derivative with respect to the scalar parameter $\sigma$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \ln|\Sigma|,$$

where $\Sigma = (\sigma^2 \Lambda_K)$ and $\Lambda_K$ is the following symmetric tridiagonal $K \times K$ matrix
$$
\Lambda_{K} =
\left(
  \begin{array}{ccccc}
    2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    -1 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & \ldots & -1 & 2 \\
  \end{array}\right).
$$

Is there a rule for these cases?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit (I didn't read the question carefully, here is the correct take): For any $K\times K$ matrix $\Lambda$, $\det(\sigma^2\Lambda) = \sigma^{2K}\det(\Lambda)$. Taking the log of the absolute value, we have $2K\log\sigma + \log|\det(\Lambda)|$, and then taking the derivative, the answer is $\frac{2K}{\sigma}$.

Comment: Tks for pointing that out. It was extremely simple ...